# Extracting the value labels of a categorical variable

Tags: label, extract, stata, categorical-data

I have a categorical variable comprised of `12` levels with numerical values from `1` to `12`.

Each one of these numerical values is assigned a label. For example, `1 = heart`, `2 = brain`, `3 = liver` and so on. What i would like is to do is extract the label (heart, brain, liver) and place it into a local macro. Is this possible?

I have tried lots of different commands such as `describe` and `codebook`.

I have also tried the following:

```
levelsof var, local(diseases)
```

The above code gets the levels of the categorical variable `var` and stores them in the local macro `diseases`. However this only outputs the numerical values, that is `1,2,3,4`, not the labels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a flexible solution relying on macro extended functions:

```
sysuse auto, clear

levelsof foreign, local(levels)
local lab : value label foreign

foreach l of local levels {
    local all `all' `: label `lab' `l''
}

display "`all'"
Domestic Foreign
```

If you also want to keep the numerical values change the loop as follows:

```
foreach l of local levels {
    local all `all' `l' `: label `lab' `l''
}

display "`all'"
0 Domestic 1 Foreign
```

Answer (score 2):

The `decode` command is also helpful for this issue:

```
decode var, generate(labvar)
levelsof labvar, local(diseases) clean
```

Comment: A disadvantage with this approach is that an extra variable is generated (`labvar`). This can be avoided by using a temporary variable instead. See `help tempname`.